# mp3 save timestamps of elapsed time

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, logging, mp3

I'm looking for a way to save the elapsed time of an audio file while I'm listening to it.
My idea is to press a key and to have the elapsed time logged to a file for subsequent use (for example to create cue sheets).
This used to be possible with some lua addons on vlc, but new versions don't allow that.
I'm using ubuntu and windows 10, and I'm going  to use any program that you can suggest that allows to do this.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? Many audio players offer a bookmark function, and some likely can use a keyboard shortcut to do this.

Comment: Only rhythmbox has a bookmark function (Windows and Linux), which can somehow be converted to a cuefile; all other programs are unusable or not free (mp3splt plus other obsolete and incompatible vlc add-ons).

Comment: I need to add hundreds of bookmarks to a single file so it needs to be fast and reliable, and I need to be able to generate a cue sheet.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I was looking for something like this, but for taking notes with automatic timestamps. Thanks